# Start up screen for mobile website on iPad

Tags: html, css

Im using the following script to add in startup screens for my mobile website, once its been added to the home screen.

```
<script>
(function(){

    var a;
    if(navigator.platform === "iPad") {
        a = window.orientation!==90||window.orientation === -90 ? 
             "/assets/img/startup/startup-tablet-landscape.png" :
             "/assets/img/startup/startup-tablet-portrait.png";
    }
    else {
        a = window.devicePixelRatio === 2 ? 
             "/assets/img/startup/startup-retina.png" :
             "/assets/img/startup/startup.png";
    }
    document.write('<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="' + a + '"/>');

})();
</script>
```

This works for iPhone but not for iPad, I'm testing on the new iPad, does this matter? All I get is a **white screen** before it loads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need javascript for that, you could use this snipplet and it should pick the right image automatically:

```
<!-- For iPhone 4 with high-resolution Retina display: -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png">

<!-- For first-generation iPad: -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon-72x72-precomposed.png">

<!-- For non-Retina iPhone, iPod Touch, and Android 2.1+ devices: -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png">


<!-- 320x460 for iPhone 3GS -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(max-device-width: 480px) and not (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="startup-iphone.png">

<!-- 640x920 for retina display -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="startup-iphone4.png">

<!-- iPad Portrait 768x1004 -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(min-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)" href="startup-iPad-portrait.png">

<!-- iPad Landscape 1024x748 -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(min-device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)" href="startup-iPad-landscape.png">
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/1375646